# Why are network drives (e.g. /cygdrive/w mounted to //foo/whatever) NOT showing up in an ssh connection?

Tags: cygwin, nfs

We need a user's Linux home directory (which is exported via NFS and Samba) to be that same user's home directory in a Cygwin bash shell invoked via ssh.

Shell windows at the Windows console include network mounted drives such as W: (mounted to //machine/exportedDirectory via Samba) which appears in /cygdrive/w

When connected externally with ssh, /cygdrive/w is not mounted.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be seeing an `ntsec` issue: https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.shares

I've personally never gotten it to work quite right, but from the faq it looks like there are some workarounds...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Somewhere around the "Well known SIDS" article my head exploded.